# Is there a way for a kernel module to find section addresses of another loaded module?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, kernel, kernel-module

On an x86 system, I have a Linux kernel module ("watcher module") that gets notified by the kernel each time a particular kernel module ("target") is loaded. Almost any kernel module can be a target. I use this in [an instrumentation system](http://code.google.com/p/kernel-strider/) I am working on.

When the watcher module handles such notification, it could be convenient for some reason, if the watcher knew the addresses of ELF sections of the loaded target module. Any ideas how this information could be obtained in kernel space?

Of course I could probably get the contents of the appropriate files in `/sys/module/<target_name>/sections/` in user space as soon as the target is loaded and then somehow pass this data to the watcher module but this is too clumsy. I would like to find a way to obtain this information directly in the kernel space.

As far as I have seen in the sources of the module loader, it does not store section addresses in `struct module`, just creates sysfs files for the sections. May be it is possible to somehow find the kernel objects corresponding to those files and read the needed data from these objects? Or probably use some other approach?

Comment: It seems that the kobject contained in `struct module` (`mkobj.kobj` field) is involved in the representation of the module in sysfs. I'll dig into this further when I have time. It might be possible to get to the attributes containing the names and addresses of the sections using that kobject as the starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging into how the information about the sections of a module gets into sysfs, I found no way to retrieve it without using the structure definitions internal to the kernel. Using such stuff is not an option in my project, so I have finally implemented another approach, which is, hopefully, more reliable.

In short, the idea is as follows. My kernel module uses the user-mode helper API to start a user-space process (a shell executing my script, actually). That process gets the name of the "target" kernel module as a parameter and collects the information about its sections from sysfs (`/sys/module/<target_name>/sections/`). From the user space, this information can be obtained easily. After that, it passes the collected data to my kernel module as a string via a file in debugfs. The module parses the string and validates its contents. If everything is OK, the names and start addresses of ELF sections will be available.

I admit, the trick with the user-mode helper is quite clumsy but it gets the job done.

I have prepared a sample implementation of the approach described above - see ["Sections" example](https://github.com/euspectre/kernel-strider/tree/master/devel/examples/sections).

For details on the user-mode helper API, see the code in `<linux/kmod.c>` and `<linux/kmod.h>` in the kernel sources, namely the definition of `call_usermodehelper()`. The examples as well as the explanation of typical usage of the API are available in [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-user-space-apps/index.html).

Note that the examples from [that article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-user-space-apps/index.html) are a bit inaccurate: the init function of the module returns the result of `call_usermodehelper()` there. The latter, however, returns 2-byte status code (at least when called with `UMH_WAIT_PROC`) rather than 0 or negative error code that init function is expected to return. This may result in runtime warnings. What `call_usermodehelper()` actually returns, is explained [here](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0904.1/00766.html).

Answer (score 1):

The file linux/kernel/module.c has some non-static functions (but without this EXPORT_SYMBOL in front) like module_address_lookup(), but these functions use things like preempt_disable() and _enable(). I'd rather not use this functions and would suggest to use sysfs-interface instead, altho your driver is already in kernel mode.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I know about `module_address_lookup()` and the like. They are used in kallsyms system for symbol lookup and such. But I need a different thing, the addresses of module's _sections_ (.text, .devinit.text, .exit.text, etc.) rather than symbols. I can obtain the addresses of "init" and "core" areas of the module but each of these may contain more than one ELF section.

Comment: It seems from the source code of the loader that by the time the loading notifications are issued, the information about the sections of the just loaded module is avaliable in sysfs only. If I am not mistaken, each file in sysfs is backed by a kernel object. If you have an idea how could my module find such objects corresponding to the files in `/sys/module/<target_name>`, that would be great.

Comment: I see no way to get this information from within the kernel, unless you modify kernel/module.c to export a symbol or function. You could try to send in a patch with a reasonable message, why you'd want it this way.

Comment: Yes, module-related stuff itself does not allow this. I've probably found a solution but it is not very reliable. `struct module` contains a kobject corresponding to the needed directory in sysfs. There are exported functions for traversal of such directories. When one gets to the dentry for a section, `show()` "method" of the mentioned kobject can be called to obtain the contents of the needed attribute as a string which can then be parsed with strtoul-like functions. This might work but it requires definitions from fs/sysfs/sysfs.h, an internal header file.

Comment: (continued) I would prefer to stay away from that internal API. May be I could get away with `call_usermodehelper` stuff, spawn a user-space process this way, make it get the data and pass it back to the kernel. User-mode helper API is rather stable and is already used for many tasks in the kernel. I'll probably investigate this approach.